# Python Text Extraction from parsed web pages

Tags: python, algorithm, text, html-parsing, text-extraction

I'm working to develop a small system for extracting content from web pages (I know it has been done, but it is a good exercise and something I need). Basically, I'm looking to extract content-content, i.e. if it is an article, I just want the article text and nothing else.

I've just started, so consider me a dumb blank slate. I'm interested in how you do it, and with what, specifically in python but I'd be interested in any

EDIT:

I've found [this](http://ai-depot.com/articles/the-easy-way-to-extract-useful-text-from-arbitrary-html/) rather enlightening and more in tune with what I'm trying to do, so solutions, discussion, and library suggestions along 'this type of thing' appreciated.

Comment: Use mechanize for navigating the pages and BeautifulSoup for parsing the HTML.

Comment: I have the basics in place for getting the html, so basically "I have pile of html, I don't know the exact configuration of where everything is in it, but I need to extract its content sans the bs surrounding it"

Comment: @blueblank Thats where BeautifulSoup comes in. It parses the HTML into a tree which you can search. You need to have a tag or string you can search for though so hopefully your html has lots of clear <div> tags that tell you what everything is.. otherwise you need to get creative with regex.  This is the normal way. If you really know NOTHING about your HTML then yes you need an AI approach as in the article you linked. That is an AI question more than a scraping question though.

Comment: ok then, I need to rephrase and reposition my line of questioning (which I sort of did halfway through) toward that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a little bit of this and I recommend the combination of [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

I would recommend parsing the HTML tree with beautiful soup and looking for a distinctive tag that identifies the content, perhaps:

```
<div id="article">
```

Then you can just take that node from the "soup".

Comment: Yes, `BeautifulSoup` is the way to go as it also works with improper XHTML.

Comment: ok, great suggestion, and I already have this pulling the html page and I have masses of html, each page might be different or not have distinct markings of where the content is....I don't know each page and a lot is going to be done as automatically & algorithmic as possible without having to focus energy on finding out each page's idiosyncrasies.